# App Rejected Because of Beta Testing Reference

Tags: ios, app-store

Ok, here a new one. I submitted an iOS app update. The only thing I changed was a few things within pages. After it was submitted, Apple rejected it and said that there was a reference to beta testing. They were nice enough to provide a screenshot where if you 3D Touch the app icon it brings an option to send beta feedback. Now the thing is I didn't add that and when I test it on my end there is nothing like that. Just the 3D Touch option for dark mode. I know that this beta testing option shows up when using it through TestFlight, but Apple shouldn't be seeing that and when I test it in the iOS simulator, it doesn't show that for me.
Thus far, Apple has been no help and hasn't been able to provide any information on how to remove it. I'm quite confused as to how to remove it, since I didn't add it and when I test it on my end I don't see it. So I'm reaching out to see if anyone has any suggestions on how to remove the 3D Touch beta testing feedback action, as I didn't add it and because of that, I don't know where or how to remove it. I've attached the screenshot that Apple sent me in case you need to see what I'm talking about. Thanks for the help!
[image]

Comment: Did they reject an app submitted for TestFlight or the App Store?

Comment: It was meant for the App Store. I did some testing in TestFlight before and it didn't get rejected. Only when I submitted the update to the App Store.

Comment: @iap-Software Of course, it was not rejected when you submitted the build for TestFlight. TestFlight only exists for Beta-testing ;-) By default, your app has NO 3D Touch Actions. You must have added it by yourself. That's why Apple didn't tell you how to remove it. I would recommend you, to read a tutorial how to **create** these shortcuts. Then you will now, where you can remove them

Comment: I added the dark mode 3D Touch action, but I didn't add the beta testing one. That's why I'm so confused on how to remove the beta testing one, since I didn't add it.